# Dynamic control creation

Tags: asp.net

I read about the dynamic control creation in ASP.NET this piece of text:

> ...When using dynamic controls, you
>   must remember that they will exist
>   only until the next postback. ASP.NET
>   will not re-create a dynamically added
>   control. If you need to re-create a
>   control multiple times, you should
>   perform the control creation in the
>   Page.Load event handler. This has the
>   additional benefit of allowing you to
>   use view state with your dynamic
>   control. Even though view state is
>   normally restored before the Page.Load
>   event, if you create a control in the
>   handler for the Page.Load event,
>   **ASP.NET will apply any view state
>   information that it has after the
>   Page.Load event handler ends. This
>   process is automatic** ...

I wanted to try it on example
create a button declaratively -

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" 
             onclick="Button1_Click"  />
```

and dynamically on behind code 5 checkboxes -

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
    {
      var chBox = new HtmlInputCheckBox();
      Controls.Add(chBox);
    }

}
```

But when i check some checkboxes and hit the button, after postback all checkboxes
states are erased. It mean ASP.NET does not manage view states of dynamic controls
automatically? I tried to enable view state to each of checkbox and for whole page, 
but its doesn't work.
Can someone explain:
1. Why is it so?
2. How to avoid this?

Comment: Hi. See the updated code in my comment, hope it works. If not, write me a comment, and I'll see if I can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The controls can be created on Page_Init.

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArguments e)
{
  //Generate the checkboxes dynamically here.
  CheckBox c;
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    c = new CheckBox();
    c.ID = "Checkbox" + i.ToString();

    divContainer.Controls.Add(c); //create a div with runat="Server" attribute or use an asp:Panel, etc. container controls.
  }
}
```

After that, try clicking the button again, the state will be always be maintained.

Comment: I did it as you and Andrew Hare said, but no change, can i publish my aspx somewhere here?

Answer (score 2):

The reason this is happening is because in order for ASP.NET to restored POSTed values, those controls need to be a part of the page before Load.  In order to make this work you need to (if possible) create your controls OnInit of the page.

Comment: private void Page_Init(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
            {
                var chBox = new HtmlInputCheckBox();
                Controls.Add(chBox);
            }
        }
no change :(

Comment: As the OP quoted, this will work already for controls created in PageLoad

Answer (score 0):

You must set an ID for each dynamic control so that they can be synchronized across postbacks.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand - there is no matter where to create controls in OnInit or OnLoad
(but some books suggests in onLoad),  *the matter is where to place them* - if 
you place through Controls.Add - it place them out of `<form></form>` so postback 
does not takes control's states. after cretating a placeholder inside `<form></form>`  and add dynamic controls to this placeholder everthing start to work fine.